# read_png in MATPLOTLIB is blurry

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to stitch a .png into a scatter plot from MATPLOTLIB. Unfortunately, the image quality of the inset image is horrible. How can I fix this?

[image: see blurry inset image]

```
  png_file = open("blah.png",'r')
  arr_lena = read_png(png_file)

  imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_lena, zoom=0.2)

  ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (99.17,68.006),
      xybox=(100,0.),
      xycoords='data',
      boxcoords="offset points",
      pad=0.5,
      arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
        connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90,rad=3")
      )


  ax.add_artist(ab)
```

Comment: try changing the `interpolation` argument, `OffsetImage(..., interpolation='gaussian')`.

Comment: This did not make the inset images of better quality.

Answer (score 3):

When saving the Figure, you can set the `dpi`. That fixes the quality of the `png` images. For example:

```
plt.savefig('my_figure.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=400)
```